# Execute curl -X with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to execute the next command using ansible playbook:

```
curl -X POST -d@mesos-consul.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://marathon.service.consul:8080/v2/apps
```

How can I run it?

If I run:

```
- name: post to consul
  uri:
    url: http://marathon.service.consul:8080/v2/apps/
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('file','mesos-consul.json') }}"
    body_format: json
    HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
```

I have the next fail:

`fatal: [172.16.8.231]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! the` `file_name '/home/ikerlan/Ik4-Data-Platform/ansible/playbooks/Z_PONER_EN_MARCHA/dns-consul/mesos-consul.j2' does not exist, or is not readable"}`

Comment: Try pasting your curl command into https://curlconverter.com/ansible/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the [URI module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html):

```
tasks:
- name: post to consul
  uri:
    url: http://marathon.service.consul:8080/v2/apps/
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('file','mesos-consul.json') }}"
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
```

Since your json file is on the remote machine the easiest way to execute is probably with the shell module:

```
- name: post to consul
  shell: 'curl -X POST -d@/full/path/to/mesos-consul.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://marathon.service.consul:8080/v2/apps'
```

Comment: Thanks @smiller171 but it tryes to execute the file 'mesos-consul.json' of the playbook, and not of the remote machine, I have a fail when I execute your module, it is in the description.

Comment: You can either use the [fetch module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html) to retrieve the json file from the remote node, and then use the URI module, or you can use the "script" module to execute the curl comand on the remote node. I can update my answer to illustrate whichever you prefer.

Comment: I think using script module is the easiest way to run the command, I don't know so much because I don't have so much experience wich ansible, so please I would like the easiest way to understand. Thanks @smiller171

Comment: Updated with shell module alternative.